# Can't define two var in javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I want to define two or more var in my javascript code,but when I define the second one, the first one becomes invalid.I have searched this problem, but I don't why. Can anybody tell me how to deal with this?
Here is my javascript code(It's used to convert JSON to HTML table):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var v_first = {{ pass_kegg|safe }}
         var v_seconde = {{ pass_tmp|safe }}

         function buildHtmlTable(myList) {
            //Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
         }

         function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
         {
             //Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not containall records
         }
    </script>
```

When I define only one variable,all things works fine. But when I fine the second variable`v_second`,the first variable `v_first` becomes invalid.

Comment: Javascript statements end in semicolons.

Comment: In the `var v_first = {{ pass_kegg|safe }}` part, what are the double braces for?  Are they being replaced at the server side?  If not, remove them, to make it `var v_first = pass_kegg|safe` and `var v_seconde = pass_tmp|safe` and see if that does what you want.

Comment: @LukePark Make it an answer and I'll vote for it

Comment: Thank you for you guys' answer, the `pass_kegg` is a variable passed from Flask App,so it will be replaced at the server side.

Comment: What do you mean by *"... becomes invalid"*? What does the generated script look like (you can see it by viewing the page source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you should be using the [`tojson()` filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters) for dynamic JavaScript generation, ie

```
var v_first = {{ pass_kegg|tojson|safe }},
    v_seconde = {{ pass_tmp|tojson|safe }};
```

It's good practice to terminate expressions with a semi-colon but it's definitely not *required*. See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
     var v_first = { pass_kegg|safe };
     var v_seconde = {pass_tmp|safe };
```

instead of this

```
     var v_first = {{ pass_kegg|safe }}
     var v_seconde = {{ pass_tmp|safe }}
```

this may work not 100% on it